# Renaming a bunch of files using Command-line

Tags: command-line

Suppose I have a folder with thousands of photos named all randomly. How can one rename them as photo1, photo2,...,photo1000 from the command-line/terminal?

Comment: If it's for Photos ( and not other kind of files ), then ExifTool is the tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will assume that you want to keep a proper suffix on the filenames:

```
c=1; for f in *.jpg ; do mv "$f" "photo$c.jpg" ; c=$(($c+1)) ; done
```

#### Notes

- `c=1`:  This initalizes the counter.  You can set it to any number you like.
- `for f in *.jpg ; do`:  This signifies the beginning of a shell `for`-loop.  While much of shell-scripting can be difficult to make work when file names can contain spaces, newlines or other difficult characters, this construction is safe against even the most hostile file names.
- `mv "$f" "photo$c.jpg"`:  This uses the counter `c` and does the actual renaming of files.  The file name `$f` is in double-quotes to protect the name from the various possible shell expansions.
- `c=$(($c+1))`: This increments the counter for the next loop
- `done`:  The signifies the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: `mv "$f" "$(printf 'photo%04d.jpg' $c)"` will give all of the files a 4-digit, zero-padded number so that they will sort correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code :

```
for i in *.jpg; do let j+=1 ; mv "$i" "photo$j.jpg" ; done
```

Comment: You may want to put `$i` inside double-quotes to protect it from word splitting in case his file names have spaces or other difficult characters in them.